# Ignoring files while updating

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, rename

I did the following commands:

```
sudo rename 's/\.list$/.list.disable/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo aptitude -f install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386=9.2.1-1ubuntu3 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386=9.2.1-1ubuntu3`
```

Now everytime I try `sudo apt-get update` I get the following:

```
N: Ignoring file 'linrunner-tlp-trusty.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'fossfreedom-rhythmbox-plugins-trusty.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'atareao-atareao-trusty.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'webupd8team-sublime-text-2-trusty.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

My questions are: What exactly have I done to my system and how can I revert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
rename 's/\.list$/.list.disable/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

renamed all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` from `*.list` to `*.list.disabled`.

Probably the easiest to do would be to turn the rename around:
So that would be ...

```
rename 's/\.list.disable$/.list/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list.disable
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

Repository sources are kept in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. This file tells apt which repositories to check for updates.

When several extra repositories are added, the list can get long and hard to maintain; so `.list` files are sometimes added to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. This makes it easier to enable and disable repositories as you need them. Behind the scenes `apt` just reads them all in the main list file before executing the check for updates.

You used `sed` to change the file names of all of the files in `sources.list.d` to `.list.disable`, which -- well, disabled them.

The message from `apt` is:

```
...it has an invalid filename extension
```

You need to change the extensions of these files back to just `.list` in order to enable them again.